# KMeans Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, error-handling

The KMeans code was working before but now it's not. The change I made was "pip install scikit-image" which I think changed numpy 1.18.5 to numpy 1.22.3 . But then I changed numpy back to 1.18.5 by doing -m pip install numpy==1.18.5 --user . And this didn't fix the issue. Any ideas what else it could be? Also, I don't remember why I had to install scikit-image (again?). Is there anyway to tell which module is incompatible with the KMeans code I'm using? KMeans is from sklearn.cluster

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~\Documents\UCSDproject\Interactive Framework\Framework_functions_modified.py in cluster_imgs(num_clusters)
    110     kmodel = KMeans(n_clusters = k,  random_state=728)
    111     kmodel.fit(pred_images) #removed n_jobs=-1 b/c no longer kmeans feature (1/14/22)
--> 112     kpredictions = kmodel.predict(pred_images)
    113     shutil.rmtree(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\UCSDproject\Interactive Framework\Framework_clustered_imgs")
    114 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py in predict(self, X, sample_weight)
   1332         sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X, dtype=X.dtype)
   1333 
-> 1334         return _labels_inertia_threadpool_limit(
   1335             X, sample_weight, x_squared_norms, self.cluster_centers_, self._n_threads
   1336         )[0]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py in _labels_inertia_threadpool_limit(X, sample_weight, x_squared_norms, centers, n_threads)
    753 ):
    754     """Same as _labels_inertia but in a threadpool_limits context."""
--> 755     with threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api="blas"):
    756         labels, inertia = _labels_inertia(
    757             X, sample_weight, x_squared_norms, centers, n_threads

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in threadpool_limits(limits, user_api)
    312         return controller.limit(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)
    313     else:
--> 314         return threadpoolctl.threadpool_limits(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)
    315 
    316 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, limits, user_api)
    169             self._check_params(limits, user_api)
    170 
--> 171         self._original_info = self._set_threadpool_limits()
    172 
    173     def __enter__(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _set_threadpool_limits(self)
    266             return None
    267 
--> 268         modules = _ThreadpoolInfo(prefixes=self._prefixes,
    269                                   user_api=self._user_api)
    270         for module in modules:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    338 
    339             self.modules = []
--> 340             self._load_modules()
    341             self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _load_modules(self)
    371             self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372         elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373             self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
    374         else:
    375             self._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self)
    483 
    484                 # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 485                 self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    486         finally:
    487             kernel_32.CloseHandle(h_process)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513             if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514                 module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515                 module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516                 self.modules.append(module)
    517 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604         self.internal_api = internal_api
    605         self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606         self.version = self.get_version()
    607         self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608         self._get_extra_info()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in get_version(self)
    644                              lambda: None)
    645         get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646         config = get_config().split()
    647         if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648             return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: I think this means the OpenBLAS library (which numpy uses) is not loaded correctly. Post the output of `np.__config__.show()`

Answer (score 2):

upgrading this:
pip install -U threadpoolctl
solved the prb for me.

Answer (score 0):

seems like fixed an issue by importing a specific version of numpy

```
import numpy 
numpy.__version__ 
'1.21.4'
```

make sure, you not importing

```
import numpy as np
```

afterwards